# why Groupby multiple columns doesn't work

Tags: python, pandas, merge

I have the following pandas

```
Time    Vehicle1    Vehicle2
0   86.0    17.0    3.0
1   90.0    17.0    8.0
2   91.0    17.0    8.0
3   92.0    17.0    8.0
4   92.0    17.0    8.0
```

I would like to merge the columns according to all three columns value, hence, the result should be

```
Time    Vehicle1    Vehicle2
0   86.0    17.0    3.0
1   90.0    17.0    8.0
2   91.0    17.0    8.0
3   92.0    17.0    8.0
```

I've tried `res=res.groupby(["Time", "Vehicle1","Vehicle2"])`, however, I get the same dataframe as shown first, what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: You need `drop_duplicates`, not `groupby`.

Comment: Not exactly sure, what you're trying to achieve, but try adding a method to your groupby ```res.groupby(["Time", "Vehicle1","Vehicle2"])["Time"].value_counts()```